# SMLNJ Error: type constructor list given 0 arguments, wants 1

Tags: compiler-errors, sml, smlnj

I am very new at standard ML and I can't find a way to fix this error:

```
fun without_i (num:int) (lista:list) (result:list) (lcm_wi:real)=
    if (num>=N-1) then result
    else
      let
        val a = (gcd(lista,lcm_wi))
        val b = List.nth(lista,num)
      in
        without_i (num+1) lista ((lcm_wi)::result) ((b/a)*lcm_wi)
      end
;

val before_i_rev = without_i 0 Rate [] 1.0;
```

Error: type constructor list given 0 arguments, wants 1.

How can I fix this error??
Also, is there a way to convert a REAL to an INT ??

Comment: Hi Ilia, and welcome to StackOverflow! For future questions, please explain what your code is supposed to do ("*without i*"?) and make it self-contained, i.e., executable without referring to unknown bits of code like `N`, `gcd`, `lcm`.

Comment: What is `Rate`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this error?

- When you pipe this program through [Moscow ML](http://try.mosml.org/), it gives a slightly more readable error:

  ```
  ! Toplevel input:
  ! fun without_i (num:int) (lista:list) (result:list) (lcm_wi:real)=
  !                                ^^^^
  ! Arity mismatch!
  ```

  Here, `list` is the type constructor and it expects a type as an argument in front of it, e.g. `(lista : real list)`. In SML you can't refer to type constructors without their type arguments. *Values* like `alist` cannot have type `list` alone.

  There are cases where you might want to refer to type constructors without their arguments but also can't. For example, if you want to define a type alias `type stack = list`, you still have to write out the type arguments:

  ```
  type 'a stack = 'a list
  ```
- You don't need explicit type annotations; you can use type inference:

  ```
  fun without_i num lista result lcm_wi =
      if num >= N-1 then result
      else
        let
          val a = gcd(lista, lcm_wi)
          val b = List.nth(lista, num)
        in
          without_i (num+1) lista ((lcm_wi)::result) ((b/a)*lcm_wi)
        end
  ```

  *(In this example, parentheses and whitespace has been reformatted, too.)*
- I'm really not sure what you mean by `gcd` and `lcm` when your inputs aren't integers. It seems that `gcd (lista, lcm_wi)` takes a `real list` and a `real`. This is probably not the `gcd` function that is commonly known to have type `int * int -> int`.
- If your intent with `num` and `N` is to process each element of `lista`, and you only use one element of `lista` at a time and discard it, you might as well perform list recursion on this argument:

  ```
  fun without_i lista =
      let fun loop [] result lcm_wi = []  (* or [lcm_wi]? *)
            | loop (b::bs) result lcm_wi =
              let val a = gcd (lista, lcm_wi)
              in loop bs (lcm_wi::result) ((b/a)*lcm_wi)
              end
      in loop lista [] 1.0 end
  ```

  By passing `lista` to `loop` that removes one `b` at a time, you get to refer to both the full `lista` and each `b` recursively.

> Is there a way to convert a real to an int?

You can convert reals to ints in many ways: [`floor`, `ceil`, `trunc`, `round`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.floor:VAL).

It all depends on what you intend to do with the fractional part.